# how to find number of occurences in ssis

Tags: ssis

Could someone please suggest which transformation i need to use for the below solution

I want to know how many times response 1 has occured for Question no.1 and how many times response 2 has occured for Question no.1 and so on

Thanks in advance

Below is the table

```
Questions   Response
Question 1  1
Question 2  2
Question 3  1
Question 4  2
Question 5  4
Question 6  4
Question 7  4
Question 8  1
Question 9  2
Question 10 1
Question 11 1
Question 12 5
Question 13 4
Question 14 4
Question 15 2
Question 16 4
Question 17 4
Question 18 3
Question 19 2
Question 20 2
Question 21 2
Question 22 2
Question 23 5
Question 24 5
Question 25 1
Question 26 2
Question 27 2
Question 28 5
Question 29 2
Question 30 2
Question 31 1
Question 32 3
Question 33 1
Question 34 5
Question 35 5
Question 36 1
Question 37 1
Question 38 1
Question 39 3
Question 40 3
Question 41 1
Question 42 5
Question 43 3
Question 44 5
Question 45 1
Question 46 2
Question 47 3
Question 48 5
Question 49 2
Question 50 3
Question 1  4
Question 2  4
Question 3  1
Question 4  1
Question 5  4
Question 6  5
Question 7  2
Question 8  5
Question 9  1
Question 10 4
Question 11 4
Question 12 5
Question 13 4
Question 14 2
Question 15 3
Question 16 1
Question 17 2
Question 18 4
Question 19 5
Question 20 5
Question 21 3
Question 22 5
Question 23 1
Question 24 2
Question 25 5
Question 26 2
Question 27 3
Question 28 3
Question 29 5
Question 30 5
Question 31 5
Question 32 4
Question 33 5
Question 34 1
Question 35 4
Question 36 1
Question 37 5
Question 38 3
Question 39 4
Question 40 5
Question 41 3
Question 42 5
Question 43 2
Question 44 3
Question 45 4
Question 46 5
Question 47 5
Question 48 1
Question 49 3
Question 50 5
Question 1  2
Question 2  2
Question 3  5
Question 4  5
Question 5  4
Question 6  2
Question 7  5
Question 8  4
Question 9  1
Question 10 2
Question 11 3
Question 12 4
Question 13 4
Question 14 2
Question 15 5
Question 16 5
Question 17 5
Question 18 2
Question 19 4
Question 20 4
Question 21 3
Question 22 5
Question 23 4
Question 24 3
Question 25 1
Question 26 4
Question 27 2
Question 28 5
Question 29 2
Question 30 1
Question 31 2
Question 32 3
Question 33 3
Question 34 2
Question 35 5
Question 36 1
Question 37 3
Question 38 1
Question 39 4
Question 40 3
Question 41 1
Question 42 5
Question 43 2
Question 44 1
Question 45 4
Question 46 1
Question 47 2
Question 48 5
Question 49 3
Question 50 3
Question 1  2
Question 2  3
Question 3  3
Question 4  2
Question 5  4
Question 6  2
Question 7  4
Question 8  2
Question 9  2
Question 10 5
Question 11 1
Question 12 2
Question 13 4
Question 14 2
Question 15 2
Question 16 1
Question 17 3
Question 18 1
Question 19 3
Question 20 2
Question 21 1
Question 22 4
Question 23 1
Question 24 1
Question 25 4
Question 26 2
Question 27 3
Question 28 1
Question 29 1
Question 30 5
Question 31 5
Question 32 3
Question 33 2
Question 34 3
Question 35 3
Question 36 3
Question 37 2
Question 38 2
Question 39 1
Question 40 4
Question 41 5
Question 42 5
Question 43 4
Question 44 2
Question 45 1
Question 46 1
Question 47 5
Question 48 3
Question 49 3
Question 50 1
Question 1  1
Question 2  3
Question 3  2
Question 4  4
Question 5  2
Question 6  1
Question 7  4
Question 8  5
Question 9  2
Question 10 3
Question 11 2
Question 12 2
Question 13 3
Question 14 1
Question 15 3
Question 16 1
Question 17 3
Question 18 1
Question 19 3
Question 20 4
Question 21 1
Question 22 3
Question 23 3
Question 24 4
Question 25 3
Question 26 4
Question 27 3
Question 28 1
Question 29 3
Question 30 2
Question 31 5
Question 32 1
Question 33 5
Question 34 4
Question 35 4
Question 36 2
Question 37 3
Question 38 4
Question 39 3
Question 40 2
Question 41 4
Question 42 1
Question 43 3
Question 44 5
Question 45 4
Question 46 5
Question 47 5
Question 48 2
Question 49 1
Question 50 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Aggregate transform to group by Question and Response. Then have another column that is a count. It can be a count of any existing column, but to make it easier, I would create a new column before your Aggregate, using a Derive Column box, and then do a count on that. That column can just be a DT_I4 that always has the value 1.

The output of this will be one row per question, per response (1-5). Each row will also have a count of how many times that response to that question was used.